# Munin Mysql plugin and notifications

Tags: munin

I can't figure out which trigger I could set in order to send an automatic notification in case mysql server stops by any cause (mem fault or whatever)

Most of the triggers I've found are only related to status within the mysql processing not status of the mysql server itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: Munin is mostly for measuring values (to produce pretty graphs); it can generate alerts as a side effect. Usually nagios or icinga is used for alerting. Of course, you can use one of the munin plugins, and configure a notification to be sent if the value is unknown (due to the process not running).

Comment: @wurtel can you give me an example of this?
I've choosen munin because I'm only looking for this simple effect and something lightweight enough, think that nagios is much heavier for a very little server.